# How to get the model architecture from .h5 and .json file?

Tags: keras, model, architecture, deep-learning

I have a pre-trained Keras model with ".h5" and ".json" file. I want to know the architecture of the model used and the names of the layers. Is there anyway I can do that?

I am new to this so I don't really know where to start

I am expecting logs that you get when you load a tensorflow model.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, first load the model and then produce a summary of the model:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('your_model.hdf5')

model.summary()
```

The summary will contain layer names and input/output shapes.